# Unrecognized command 'run-eject'

Tags: react-native, mobx, create-react-app

I want to eject my react-native so I can install mobx but running both 'yarn run eject' and 'npm run eject' doesn't work.i think this is new issue and so couldn't find help online. any help would be appreciated. 
this is my package.json file and the error given below[image: Here is the photo].

```
{
  "name": "a2x",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-native run-eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "mobx": "^5.5.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.8",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm run eject`..not `npm run-eject`
But if you trying to add native dependencies later i think better to start project using `react native init`. not `using create-react-native-app`.

Comment: sorry but I have tried that also. plus how is init different from create-react-native-app.

Comment: though when I run 'react-native eject', it does something and then display the msg 'Both the iOS and Android folders already exist! Please delete `ios` and/or `android` before ejecting.'

Comment: When run `react-native init` it ll create iOS and Android folders when creating the app.So no need to add them later. No need to use run eject later. if iOS and Android folders exists then no need to do `run eject` again.if you want to run eject you have to delete iOS and android folders and there are some js files too. then execute `npm run eject`.

Answer (score 1):

Actual command is `react-native eject`.

It will create new folder for android and iOS to run it seperately on native.

As you said you are getting error of `Both the iOS and Android folders already exist!`, so please delete it and try with this command.

If you already have android and ios folder with some native implementation, there is no need to use `eject` command at all.

regarding `npm run reject` command, I guess [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/816lou/what_does_npm_run_eject_do/) will be more useful to clear everything.

Answer (score 0):

Always working for me, only follow two steps
first install in your project

```
yarn add react-native-eject
```

and then run

```
react-native eject
```

make sure you have install yarn in your pc